# Is there a way to bind a variable to multiple alternatives in a switch statement?

Tags: swift

Suppose I have an enum definition as follows:

```
enum Response {
    case Result(String, Int)
    case Error(String)
}
```

Then, I get such a response:

```
let resp: Response = // ...
```

Suppose I want to write a switch statement and handle the same way the Result and the Error cases and bind a variable of the same name to the `String` they contain. How can I do this? Conceptually, something similar to this:

```
switch resp {
    case let .Result(str, _), let .Error(str):
        println("Found: \(str)")
}
```

where `str` is bound twice, and `_` signals that I'm not interested in the `Int` value that a `Result` carries.

So far, the closest thing I could find was to declare an inline function like this and then call it:

```
func processRespString(str: String) {
    println("Found \(str)")
}

switch resp {
    case let .Result(str, _): processRespString(str)
    case let .Error(str): processRespString(str)
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: When you have more than one pattern to match, you can't declare a variable in the pattern. For your particular case, I think the way you did is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Swift evolution Proposal SE-0043](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0043-declare-variables-in-case-labels-with-multiple-patterns.md) that has been accepted fixed this issue with Swift 3.

```
enum Response {
    case result(String, Int)
    case error(String)
}

let resp = Response.error("Some text")

switch resp {
case let .result(str, _), let .error(str):
    print("Found: \(str)") // prints Found: Some text
}
```

With Swift 2,  the previous Playground code would generate an error: `case labels with multiple patterns cannot declare variables`. However, with Swift 3, it generates no errors and has the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

No, but if you want to access the String value of a Response regardless of whether it is a .Result or an .Error, you can do this:

```
enum Response {
    case Result(String, Int)
    case Error(String)

    func Message() -> String {
        switch self {
            case let .Result(str, _):
                return str
            case let .Error(str):
                return str
        }
    }
}

var resp: Response = .Error("Fault")
resp = .Result("Success",5)

println(resp.Message())
```

This way you keep the logic for the enum inside the enum itself.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way would be to signify an error by using an **optional** instead of the enum:

```
struct Response {
    var string:String
    var result: Int?
    var isError: Bool { return result == nil }
}
```

You can mix this with the original code if you insist on having an enum –

```
// Auxiliary enum
enum IntResponse {
    case Result(Int)
    case Error()
}

struct FullResponse {

    // Real properties 
    var string: String
    var response: IntResponse

    // Convenience property
    var result: Int? { 
        switch(response) {
            case let .Result(value): return value
            case let .Error(): return nil
        }
    }

    // Initializers for success and error
    init(errorString:String) {
        self.string = errorString
        self.response = IntResponse.Error()
    }
    init(string:String, result:Int) {
        self.string = string
        self.response = IntResponse.Result(result)
    }
}

// An example usage

let error = FullResponse(errorString: "some error")
let success = FullResponse(string: "success", result: 10)

func do_something(response: FullResponse) {
    println(response.string)  // works for any of the cases
}
```