# Possible to fall through an enum case but still use its associated value?

Tags: swift, enums

I have a `Result` enum with associated values:

```
enum Result {
    case success(object: AnyObject)
    case failure(errorMessage: String)
    case reauthenticate(errorMessage: String)
}
```

I'd like to handle the `failure` and `reauthenticate` cases identically, but also need access to the associated value. Is there a language feature in Swift which'd let me fall through the `failure` case without losing its errorMessage? Something like:

```
switch result {
    case .success(_):
        // ...
    case .failure(let errorMessage): fallthrough
    case .reauthenticate(let errorMessage:
        print(errorMessage)
}
```

I know there are other ways to handle this. For example, I could add a computed `errorMessage` var on `Result`. My question is whether it can be done inside the switch statement (using `fallthrough` or some other method).

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to bind a variable to multiple alternatives in a switch statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004826/is-there-a-way-to-bind-a-variable-to-multiple-alternatives-in-a-switch-statement).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `fallthrough` here, however you *can* match multiple cases with associated values, and bind the associated value(s) as long as the patterns for each of the variable bindings match, and the value(s) bound for each pattern share the same type(s) – as per [SE-0043](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0043-declare-variables-in-case-labels-with-multiple-patterns.md).

Therefore you can just say:

```
switch result {
case .success:
    print("success")
case .failure(let errorMessage), .reauthenticate(let errorMessage):
    print(errorMessage)
}
```